# How can enable users switching between languages with URI Language Identifier

Tags: php, codeigniter, url

I'm using this [URI Language Identifier](https://github.com/EllisLab/CodeIgniter/wiki/URI-Language-Identifier)

```
http://localhost/internationalisation/index.php/en/
http://localhost/internationalisation/index.php/en/welcome/
http://localhost/internationalisation/index.php/en/contact/
http://localhost/internationalisation/index.php/es/
http://localhost/internationalisation/index.php/es/welcome/
```

I've set `$config['lang_ignore'] = FALSE;` so the URL shows what language I'm currently using like above.

Question: How can enable users switching between languages?

These codes in View won't work:

```
<a href="<?php echo site_url('en'); ?>">English</a>
<a href="<?php echo site_url('es'); ?>">Spanish</a>
```

because they produce links like this:

```
http://localhost/internationalisation/index.php/en/en
http://localhost/internationalisation/index.php/en/es
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Followed LastCoder's first suggestion:

**CONFIG:**

```
$config['lang_ignore'] = FALSE;
```

**VIEW:**

```
<a href="<?php echo site_url('language/en'); ?>">English</a>
<a href="<?php echo site_url('language/es'); ?>">Spanish</a>
```

**CONTROLLER:**

```
class Language extends CI_Controller
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();

        $this->load->helper('url');

        $lang_uri_abbr = $this->config->item('lang_uri_abbr');

        if ($this->uri->segment(2) === false ||
            ! isset($lang_uri_abbr[$this->uri->segment(2)]))
        {
            redirect();
        }
        else
        {
            $site_url = substr(site_url(), 0, -2);

            redirect($site_url . $this->uri->segment(2));
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have a couple options...

- site_url will always return the /en or /es or whatever bit of the path at the end so you can use the string functions to mangle (remove) the end bit and add your own.
- you can set a configuration property that has the site name and reference that ("http://localhost/internationalisation/index.php"), then append your language identifier.
- you can use relative paths and the basename function with the **FILE** magic constant

> ```
> <?php echo basename(__FILE__) . '/en'; ?>
> ```